# What can I do in my code today, to prevent the unix time stamp running out in 2038?

Tags: php, algorithm, unix, time

For example, I mostly program in PHP. What can I do today to prevent my program from exploding in 2038 due to unix time stamp running out? I would love to see some specific algorithms, functions or logics that can work to prevent this problem. Thanks.

Comment: do you think the code you write today will still be in use in 2038?

Comment: use 64bit PCs by then. This should need no extra effort.

Comment: @Dagon - programmers in the 70s didn't think their code would be in use in 2000 either, but lo and behold..

Comment: @Dagon, some people who wrote mainframe code in the 70s and 80s didn't expect their code to be in use in 2000. But at least in this case, you can avoid it by using 64 bit systems, which are starting to become the norm.

Comment: @EricPetroelje lo and behold, it wasn't? Nothing really happened 1.1.2000 0:00 AM

Comment: but its php, for the web, i don't think that comparison stacks up.

Comment: @Jan - you haven't been programming very long have you :)  I spent the whole of 1998 and 1999 doing Y2K remediation on VAX VMS programs written in the 70s.  I can tell you with certainty that there were thousands of other programmers wasting millions of hours to ensure that "nothing really happened on 1/1/2000".

Comment: You could store the current era (a rolling frame of 138 years) in the config file and roll your own mod-{2^32 ms} corrections.

Comment: @EricPetroelje  You could also say that there were `.. thousands of other programmers being paid to work millions of hours .. `. :D

Comment: @Dagon In 1970, when I got my first programming job, I did worry about 2000. I only stopped worrying in the late 1990's, when worrying about it, and therefore fixing it, became fashionable.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan in 2038 i will be retired, and safe from the fallout :-)

Comment: @Dagon I'm already retired, but I would still prefer computer programs to go on working. The investments I live off are really just bits in various databases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Store the timestamp as a 64bit, or higher, integer. I'm sure MySQL will be updated by then so that `TIMESTAMP` isn't 32bit. In regards to PHP, I don't see any issues there if you're on a 64 bit server.

Comment: Does that mean not using PHP's builting date function? or do you expect the PHP date function to be updated to work after 2038?

Comment: What do you mean? Why do you think the date function wouldn't work after 2038?

Comment: The current PHP date function specifically says: "The valid range of a timestamp is typically from Fri, 13 Dec 1901 20:45:54 GMT to Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT."

Comment: @KoKo "The valid range of a timestamp is **typically** from Fri, 13 Dec 1901 20:45:54 GMT to Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT". FTFY.

Comment: +1 for bringing up external systems like MySQL. External systems and file formats (like the tcpdump packet capture format) that are inflexible and specified to use 32 bits for the time are where the real problem is. For computations on internal representations inside programming languages, the problem will largely be gone well before 2038 by the use of 64 bit types for things like `time_t`.

Comment: @KoKo don't forget to read the suffix that explains why: *"These are the dates that correspond to the minimum and maximum values for a 32-bit signed integer"*. The language controls the size, not you. And they've got 25 years to turn it into a 64-bit integer. I think they'll manage.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I now feel more comfortable using the PHP date function.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you plan on using a 32-bit server or PHP binary for the next 25 years I don't think it will be a problem.

PHP is an interpreted language, so when you write `$stamp = 1358425440;` it's just a string of text that PHP reads in, *then* allocates X bytes of memory to store it according to how *PHP* was compiled. So if you update your PHP binary to one that supports 64-bit integers then you don't have to change your code. [In theory, at least. We all know how PHP likes to change common functions around and deprecate things.]

The only consideration I can see making is for the storage of integer values outside of PHP, ie. in mySQL. In this case you just need to make sure that you're storing your timestamp as either an *UNSIGNED* INT, BIGINT, or DATETIME.

SIGNED INTs will conk out Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT, but *UNSIGNED* INTs will last until Sun, 07 Feb 2106 06:28:15 GMT.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I now feel more comfortable using the PHP date function.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that UNSIGNED INTs are good for essentially another 100 years.  I always make my INTs in MySQL unsigned-- glad to know it's good for a while!

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
 // 32 bit
    int timestampSec
```

to

```
 // 64bit
    long timestampSec
```

for internal storage.

Comment: Look at the language tag... You can't really choose one.